# Python PIL - changing colour profile to untagged RGB on crop, scale and save

Tags: python

Can't figure out why the document profile is being changed on a crop, scale and save with PIL. Have tested with an image that had sRGB as color profile, and after it has untagged RGB.

```
def scale(self, image):
    images = []

    image.seek(0)

    try:
        im = PIL.open(image)
    except IOError, e:
        logger.error(unicode(e), exc_info=True)

    images.append({"file": image, "url": self.url, "size": "original"})

    for size in IMAGE_WEB_SIZES:
        d = cStringIO.StringIO()
        try:
            im = crop(image, size["width"], size["height"])
            im.save(d, "JPEG")
            images.append({"file": d, "url": self.scale_url(size["name"]), "size": size})
        except IOError, e:
            logger.error(unicode(e), exc_info=True)
            pass

    return images
```

I am trying to get PIL to save the scaled version with the same colour profile that the original image has.

EDIT: According to this it should be possible http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.image/3215, but still not working for me using PIL 1.1.7

Comment: Did you look at the patch mentioned in the first reply of the linked discussion? It's necessary for color profile preservation to work, just updating the PIL version is not enough (in my answer below, I was also using 1.1.7, and had the same issue).

Comment: @mgibsonbr As I can see then according to the Readme file in the hack by Florian Hoech no other libraries are needed. And in 1.1.7 the hack should have been made into a feature according to http://hg.effbot.org/pil-117/commits/03e996c3b271fd3dabb008a8c694b82e3e6c5917

Answer (score 28, accepted):

PIL has a function to read the icc_profile and also a way to save with icc_profile. So what I did was to open the file to get the icc_profile:

```
try:
    im1 = PIL.open(image)
    icc_profile = im1.info.get("icc_profile")
```

And the add it to the file again on save:

```
im.save(d, "JPEG", icc_profile=icc_profile)
```

And the full code:

```
def scale(self, image):
    images = []

    image.seek(0)

    try:
        im1 = PIL.open(image)
        icc_profile = im1.info.get("icc_profile")
    except IOError, e:
        logger.error(unicode(e), exc_info=True)

    images.append({"file": image, "url": self.url, "size": "original"})

    for size in IMAGE_WEB_SIZES:
        d = cStringIO.StringIO()
        try:
            im = crop(image, size["width"], size["height"])

            im.save(d, "JPEG", icc_profile=icc_profile)
            images.append({"file": d, "url": self.scale_url(size["name"]), "size": size})
        except IOError, e:
            logger.error(unicode(e), exc_info=True)
            pass

    return images
```

I have tested with both tagged (with icc profile) and untagged jpeg images.

Answer (score 6):

**Update:** Disregard this answer, [@Christoffer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14537273/520779) is the correct one. As it turns out, `load` was not making any conversions, the ICC profile was just being saved somewhere else.

---

I don't think either of these operations are changing the color profile, but the conversion is being done right on `load`. After opening [this sample image](http://dpnow.com/galleries/showphoto.php/photo/12398) using a recent version of PIL (1.1.7 on Windows XP), it is immediatly converted to RGB:

```
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> Image.open('Flower-sRGB.jpg')
<PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=600x450 at 0xD3D3F0>
```

If I try to save it back the way it is (without changing anything), some quality is lost. If I use a lossless format OTOH, the resulting image looks fine to me:

```
>>> im = Image.open('Flower-sRGB.jpg')
>>> im.save("Flower-RBG.jpg")
>>> im.save("Flower-RBG.png")
```

Trying to convert the resulting image back to sRGB didn't work:

```
>>> im = Image.open('Flower-sRGB.jpg').convert('CMYK')
>>> im
<PIL.Image.Image image mode=CMYK size=600x450 at 0xD73F08>
>>> im.save("Flower-CMYK.png")

>>> im = Image.open('Flower-sRGB.jpg').convert('sRGB')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 702, in convert
    im = im.convert(mode, dither)
ValueError: conversion from RGB to sRGB not supported
```

I believe saving in sRGB would require some external library, like [pyCMS](http://www.cazabon.com/pyCMS/) or [LittleCMS](http://www.littlecms.com/). I haven't tried them myself, but here's a [tutorial](http://hipo.biz/en/blog/icc-profile-transformation-using-pil/) (using the latter tool) that looks promising. Finally, here's a [discussion thread](http://grokbase.com/t/python/image-sig/0861ev1hen/anyway-to-keep-icc-profiles-intact-e-g-srgb) about the same problem you're facing (keeping the color profile intact when loading/saving), hopefully it can give you some more pointers.

Comment: The color profile is changed on the image when it hits the server, so it is not on load if I understand you right. But then it should be at im = PIL.open(image) in my code that the color profile is changed.

Comment: @Christoffer Did you print/log the mode of `im` just after opening it? In my tests (see first snippet) it changes to `RGB` right away, so I still think it's on load. BTW after looking more closesly to your code, you first open `image` creating the variable `im`, but then crops `image` itself (discarding `im`). Is that right?

Comment: Don't think sRGB is a mode in it self, but just a version of the mode RGB. So if you have to check the color profile you have to log im.info.get("icc_profile"). You are right I discard the first im. Not sure why it was there as I am fixing someone else's code. But as you can see in the solution I found I now use it ;)