# Color differences in image when ByteIO is used

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, python-imaging-library, jpeg, bytesio

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

import numpy as np
import requests
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
req = requests.get("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/07/Honeycrisp-Apple.jpg", headers={
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.123 Safari/537.36"},
                   timeout=3)
img = BytesIO(req.content)
data = Image.open(img)
data.save("haha.jpg")
with open(os.path.join("haha1.jpg"), "wb") as f:
    f.write(req.content)
```

There is a brightness difference in the images as you can see below, what is the reason and how to address it?

below is haha.jpg

[image]

below is haha1.jpg

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python PIL - changing colour profile to untagged RGB on crop, scale and save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13672777/python-pil-changing-colour-profile-to-untagged-rgb-on-crop-scale-and-save) The original image has some ICC profile stored. When saving through Pillow, you need to explicitly put that ICC profile into the `save` command. Details see linked Q&A. If I follow the suggested way in the accepted answer, I get "identifcal" images.

Comment: Yes, it did answer, thanks